# Replicate just one table on slave from master

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I'm attempting to replicate a single table on a mysql slave from the corresponding table in a mysql master. I've added this configuration on the slave server:

```
replicate-wild-do-table=db.table
```

However, this replicates everything on the master in the slave. How do I restrict it to the one table?

Comment: Configure a MySQL in Master Server
Vim /etc/my.cnf
binlog-do-db=vinoth

Comment: Configure Slave Server : master-user=slave_user
master-password=redhat
replicate-do-db=vinoth

Comment: Note that you did not actually include your master and slave `cnf` files.